# error "Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Theme.Maps'" (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

I'm recieving this error on my android studios project and am unsure of what i need to do to resolve it, any tips on how to correct it?

I tried the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button but nothing changed. I also tried clicking on File --> "Invalidate Caches" but this also had no effect.